# Selenium automated tests to check XML data on backend side

Tags: java, xml, selenium, automated-tests, backend

I am working on test automation framework, which is doing combination of UI/Backend  tests.
The simplified  scenario is the following:

1. User logged in to account
2. Goes to product page and add some products to the cart
3. Goes to checkout page and places the order
4. On the Backend  side order is created in the Order Tables
5. Xml file is generated in the Backend system and stored in db

What I need is to perform 1-4 steps with selenium and then to test step 5 I need to connect to backend db and read this generated Order xml file to check it contains everything we expect.

Here I need some advise with step 5. What would be the best option to read/test xml file from backend db with Java. Is [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) something I would need to look into? So i should have some classes to connect to db, ready the data etc and then after finishing UI steps I will open DB connection, get the data, parse/verify it.

Does this approach sound reasonable? Are there any alternatives to doing this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you parse XML file or XML content ?

Comment: what do you mean? First I need to connect to backend's DB to be able to ready XML

Comment: that shouldn't be difficult. The thing is if you have a XML content would you be able to parse it ?

Comment: yes sure, I can do this, the main question is about the whole approach. I've never done this kind of testing, I mean mixing Selenium UI tests with combination of connecting to backend DB in order to get XML file etc

Answer (score 1):

So if this is about the approach then it is what lot of **automation** **project** does. Let me explain it to you.

As you have stated initial 4 steps can be done using `Java and Selenium bindings`.

Now for **5th step**, yes you would have to use Java to connect to DB.

If `DB URL, Password, SID etc`  is known to you and if it is `ORACLE/MYSQL` DB then you can use `JDBC` to connect to Database using `DriverManager`.

But if it is any specific DB, let say `CASSANDRA DB` then you would have to connect with `DataStax` and their appropriate driver.

Yes the approach is very commonly-driven and you can go ahead without any issue.

Good luck !

Comment: Are there any alternatives to doing this? - Check with your Devs if you can get the same data using any REST call. in that case Java Rest Assured can be taken into consideration

Comment: this is exactly what I am checking right now, I mean using Rest Assure would be the bets option. Thank you

Comment: @user3759563 : yes that's a good option, if FTP is supported then you could probably use that also. but in the end you would need more stability right ? so I would still prefer DB verification over anything.